# R fit restricted AR(p) model

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive

I have a question about using R to fit an AR model. If we want fit a AR(p) model, the equation will be $Y_t = φ_1Y_{t-1} + φ_2Y_{t-2} + ... + φ_pY_{t-p} + Z_t$.
What about I only want to fit the model like $Y_t = φ_1Y_{t-1} + φ_{11}Y_{t-11} + Z_t$? ($Z_t$ is white noise).
Does anyone know how to fit this model in R?

Comment: Is this some kind of seasonal model where the season is 10 months/years or something like that?

Comment: Yes, you can think about as a seasonal dataset. But the question is, when we fit AR(p) mode in R, R always gives us all the parameters from 1 to p. But here, I only want fit the model with 3(including sigam^2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `fixed` parameter to `arima()`. Specify an AR(11) model and only allow the first, eleventh and twelfth (which is $\sigma^2$) parameter to vary:

```
> set.seed(1)
> foo <- ts(rnorm(100),frequency=12)
> model <- arima(foo,order=c(11,0,0),fixed=c(NA,rep(0,9),NA,NA))
Warning message:
In arima(foo, order = c(11, 0, 0), fixed = c(NA, rep(0, 9), NA,  :
  some AR parameters were fixed: setting transform.pars = FALSE
> model

Call:
arima(x = foo, order = c(11, 0, 0), fixed = c(NA, rep(0, 9), NA, NA))

Coefficients:
          ar1  ar2  ar3  ar4  ar5  ar6  ar7  ar8  ar9  ar10     ar11  intercept
      -0.0022    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0  -0.0364     0.1083
s.e.   0.1001    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0.1059     0.0864

sigma^2 estimated as 0.7976:  log likelihood = -130.6,  aic = 269.19
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I want. May I ask what is the meaning of the vector after fix?

Comment: As per the help page (`?arima`): "If supplied, only ‘NA’ entries in ‘fixed’ will be varied.". So `fixed=c(NA,rep(0,9),NA,NA)` means that the 2nd through 10th AR parameter are fixed to zero, whereas the 1st and the 11th AR parameter as well as $\sigma^2$ (which is the twelfth model parameter) can vary. You could in principle also fix parameters to any other value. Of course, if you have an ARMA(p,q) model, your `fixed` needs to be of length p+q+1.